# Ajax - Check for database update

Tags: php, ajax

Im making a autobuy system. I have a invoice page that  show with default - payment processing. I have made it so that when they actually buy via coinpayments.net, it updates the database to status 1. I want to make it so that when the status changes to 1 in the database, it updates the invoice page without refreshing and says "Payment Status: Completed". I have some ajax and php code but it doesn't seem to be working. I update the database status to 1 and no text changes on my page.  I have a timer interval that should be updating every 2 seconds but something is wrong. Please help.

***My HTML status code***

```
<input type="hidden" id="order_numb" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['succ_itm_id']; ?>">

<div id="payment" style="text-align: center;">
    Status<br><img src="../img/processing/payment_proc.gif"><br>Payment Pending
</div>
```

***My AJAX code***

```
<script>
function send_data() {
    var order_id = $('#order_numb').val();
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../rld_payment.php',
        data: { order_num: order_id },
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#payment').innerHTML = 'Status<br><b>Payment Completed!</b><br><b>Redirecting</b> ...';
        }
    });
}

send_data();
setInterval(send_data, (2 * 1000));
</script>
```

***My PHP code to check status***

```
<?php
include('conf/db_.php');

$order_id       =   mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['order_num']);
$order_status   =   mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `status` FROM `orderinfo` WHERE `order_id` = '$order_id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
if($order_status == 1)
{
    echo 'Status<br><b>Payment Completed!</b><br><b>Redirecting</b> ...';
    return true;
}

?>
```

Comment: Please don't YELL.

Comment: @Chris I do not have a clue what you're on about sir.

Comment: Ben, typing in all capitals is considered yelling on the internet. Your title is in all capitals.

Comment: @Chris Um ... Okay. I didn't think anyone would take it to heart.

Comment: There is no JavaScript function ´header('Location:...')´ It's window.location https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: @Reeno Okay.  I will edit the code. I just checked it without, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all your help! I took the jQuery code from @Mikey and the PHP code from @Kark92 which put together, both worked superbly.

My final, working code is below:

***HTML***

```
<div id="payment" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

***jQUERY / AJAX***

```
<script>
function send_data() {
    console.log('sending data');
    $.post('../inc/rld_payment.php', function (data) {
        console.log('receiving data', data);
            $('#payment').html(data);
    });
}

send_data();
setInterval(send_data, 2000);
</script>
```

***PHP***

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conf/db_.php';

$order_id = $_SESSION['succ_itm_id'];

$sql                = "SELECT status FROM orderinfo WHERE order_id = '$order_id'";
$results = mysqli_query  ($con, $sql );
if ( !$results ) return false;
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results );
$order_status = $row ['status'];

if($order_status == 1)
{
    echo 'Payment Status: Completed';
}
else
{
    echo 'Status<br><img src="../img/processing/payment_proc.gif"><br>Payment Pending';
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to store session variable in a hidden field if you have it already stored in a session that can be easily accessed on any other page? Unless you have a valid reason for doing so, just use `$_SESSION['succ_itm_id']` in your payment script.

Second, your query only [selects](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm) the record NOT [updates](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm) the record.

I would simply do,

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include 'conf/db_.php';

$order_id = $_SESSION['succ_itm_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE orderinfo SET status = 1 WHERE order_id = $order_id");
if ($result) {
    echo 'Payment Status: Completed';
}
?>
```

In your JavaScript code, you would then not need to pass anything.

Note that the response (what you echo'd in your payment script) is stored in the `data` variable, so you can use it to add in the HTML.

Note also that `$(selector)` is always a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), not a native JavaScript element. A jQuery object doesn't have a property `innerHTML` but has a convenient [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

```
<script>
function send_data() {
    /*$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../rld_payment.php',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#payment').html(data);
        }
    });*/

    console.log('sending data');
    // shorthand method to $.ajax()
    $.post('../rld_payment.php', function (data) {
        console.log('receiving data', data);
        $('#payment').html(data);
    });
}

send_data();
setInterval(send_data, 2 * 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I update the status of the payment once they pay in my ipn.php page. All I want to do in this php page is check the status of the payment. If it's 1, it's true, if 0, it's not. Also, I unset all of my sessions on this invoice page so that they cannot re visit it without re-checking out ( if that makes sense ). So to be able to parse it through a php variable would be better if you could help with that. I'll try your code now though. Unless I can make it unset the sessions on success in the JQUERY

Answer (score -1):

You have an error on this statement :

```
if($order_status == 1)
```

mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error. So it will never return 1, then the statement was FALSE all the the time.
You must do something like this :

```
$results = mysql_query  ($conn, $sql );
if ( !$results ) return false;
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results );
$order_status = $row ['status'];
```